# $\mathfrak{F}$ contains an even number of subsets of $\Omega$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

Show that, if $\Omega$ is a finite set, then $\mathfrak{F}$ contains an even number of subsets of $\Omega$.

Proof: Let $f:\mathfrak{F}\rightarrow\mathfrak{F}$ such that $f(A)=\Omega\setminus A,\text{ }\forall A\in\mathfrak{F}$. Note that $f$ is bijective. That is, $\forall A\in\mathfrak{F},\text{ }\exists!\Omega\setminus A\neq A\in\mathfrak{F}$, so $\mathfrak{F}$ has an even number of subsets of $\Omega$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is $\mathfrak{F}$ exactly? A $\sigma$-algebra? If it's just a generic collection of subsets the premise definitely need not hold, e.g. for $\mathfrak{F} = \{\Omega\}$

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra, yes. @PrincessEev

Comment: The basic idea seems correct to me, but your proof lacks some details IMHO. For example, you have to stress that $\Omega \setminus A$ is different for each $A$. Also, the statement should exclude $\Omega = \emptyset$, in which case the=any $\sigma$-algebra contains only one element and your argument $\Omega \setminus A \neq A$ does not work).